# Unable to verify this set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $Z\subset F$, $E_1=E\cup Z$. Then $E_1^c=(E\cup F)^c \cup (F-Z)$.

In particular, if $x\in F-Z$, then x need not be in $E^c$ (e.g. $F\subset E$). Is there something I'm missing, or this equality indeed incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is wrong. Let the universe be ${\{1,2,3,4}\}$. Let $Z={\{1}\}$, $F={\{1,2,3}\}$, $E={\{2,4}\}$. But $E_1^c={\{3}\}$ and $(E \cup F)^c \cup (F-Z)={\{2,3}\}$.